# 2 longitudes C# validation

Tags: c#, gis

I have two longitudes.  We'll call them longitude A and B.  Longitude A must always be west of Longitude B.  Given both are valid values between -180 and 180 how can I create a validation routine using C# to test to see if A is west of B and A is never the same as B?  The prime meridian thing and the 180/-180 ting has me confused.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Start in Kansas and go far enough west, you'll end up in Missouri.

Comment: Technically A can always be considered west of B, unless you're asking if it's closer to B west of it as apposed to east of it?

Comment: How do you define that something is west from something? When you go west from France, you eventually reach Germany. Does that mean that Germany is west of France for you? Or is it that you always take the shorter route?

Comment: What does it mean to be west? No matter the values of A and B you can always get to B by continuing west. Do you mean you don't want to go a certian distance west? no crossing from -180 to 180? Is A west of B if you travel a shorter distance west to get there than east?

Comment: On a sphere, if you go West of B, it seems to me you will ALWAYS encounter A.   It may be 355 degrees to the west (e.g. 5 degrees east of B), but it will always be to the West at some point.   Can you clarify your constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sea navigation if the longitudes differense is negative, the first longitude is thought as more west. However, when the absolute value of the differense is greater then 180, the value is decresed from the 360 and the sign is being negated. Thus

```
bool IsMoreWest(double longitudeA, double logitudeB)
{
    double difference = longitudeA - logitudeB;
    if (Math.Abs(difference) > 180.0) {
        difference = -Math.Sign(difference) * (360.0 - Math.Abs(difference));
    }
    return difference < 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I like this answer, but I could have been more specific.  So longitudeA could be used as proposed west longitude coordinate of the 2 right?  Assuming I am understanding this correctly I am testing using information about the Aleutian islands. 170 in the eastern hemisphere as longA and -155 in the western hemisphere as longB.   (170 - -155)=325. 325>180=true. (-1) * (35)=-34.  return true;  Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: And if I did just the opposite to attempt incorrect data: longA=-155 and longB=170.  (-155-170)=-325. 325>180=true. 1 * 685.  return false.

Comment: It seems that your calculations are almost correct. I just want to do some minor fixes: in first case the result is -35 (not -34) since it's the multiplication; in the second case the result is 35 (not 685), since the absolute value is being subtracted.

Answer (score 1):

```
//minutes and seconds to right of . for simplicity
public void Validate(Decimal dLongitudeA, Decimal dLongitudeB)
{
    if( (dLongitudeB + 360 - dLongitudeA) % 360 < 180 )
       throw new ApplicationException("Validation Failed.");
}
```

Assuming I'm not backwards or something...

Comment: Doesn't look like a situation where `Decimal` is better than `Double` to me.